# Error on an IF function format SQL: Error Not Supported BOOL, STRING, BOOL, only IF(BOOL, ANY, ANY)

Tags: sql, if-statement, google-bigquery, format

I'm trying to write an IF statement in SQL, and it's throwing an error about the supported format

> SQL_ANALYSIS_ERROR: No matching signature for function IF for argument types: BOOL, BOOL, STRING. Supported signature: IF(BOOL, ANY, ANY)

Code:  `IF(field1 = 'string_1', field2 , 'string_2') AS field_name`

This should meet the requirement of BOOL, ANY, ANY....but for whatever reason it's not. Anyone have suggestions? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Is field1 a boolean? It seems so.

Comment: The system is closest to mySQL if i had to guess, and yes field1 is a bool

Comment: Closest to MySQL? What system is it actually? And you are trying to compare a bool to a string - how does that work?

Comment: When I google the error message, it turns out to be Google BigQuery.

Comment: Cast `field2` to string - it seems it has BOOL datatype. `IF(field1 = 'string_1', CAST(field2 AS CHAR), 'string_2') AS field_name`

Comment: `IF` requires that both `ANY` arguments be the same type, so that it knows what the type of the whole expression will be.

Comment: If this is supposed to be a field name, why are you using a boolean column as a possible value?

Comment: That was the problem -- both ANY arguments had to be the same field type - thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I think with you confuse. the function is IIF.

EX:
`SELECT IIF('string_1' = 'string_1', 'OK' , 'string_2')`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

The SQL standard for conditional logic is `CASE`:

```
(CASE WHEN field1 = 'string_1' THEN field2 ELSE 'string_2' END) AS field_name
```

I recommend this over bespoke functions such as `if`.

In this case, the problem is that `field2` is `BOOLEAN`, so it needs to be converted.  BigQuery requires explicit conversion in most cases, so:

```
(CASE WHEN field1 = 'string_1' THEN CAST(field2 AS STRING) ELSE 'string_2' END) AS field_name
```